# Adding a class to Formtastic radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have a Formtastic radio button collection which is populated by a number of types:

```
<%= f.input :type_id, :validate => true, :as => :radio, :collection => Type.where(:object_type => 'Post') %>
```

However, I want to conditionally add a class to each choice, since some of the radio buttons need to be disabled depending on a certain condition.

For example, a `:member_class =>` param would be ideal, but I don't believe it exists like `:member_label` and `:member_value`.

Does Formtastic have the ability to allow this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <%= f.input :type_id, :validate => true, :as => :radio,
       :collection => Type.where(:object_type => 'Post'), 
       :input_html => { :class => (:class_name if condition_goes_here)  } %>
```

or

```
    <%= f.input :type_id, :validate => true, :as => :radio,
        :collection => Type.where(:object_type => 'Post'),
        :input_html => { :disabled => (:disabled if condition_goes_here)  } %>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in thanking you for this. This should work but do you know how I would get the value of the current :type_id in this case, to use within the condition?

Comment: This is kind of a late answer but I found the solution in the radio input doc : you can pass specific options with a third element in a collection array.   http://www.rubydoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Inputs/RadioInput 

So, in your case, you could do something like this 

    <%= f.input :type_id, :validate => true, :as => :radio,
        :collection => Type.where(:object_type => 'Post').map{|post| [post.to_s, post.id, {disabled: post.disabled_radio?}]},
        :input_html => { :disabled => (:disabled if condition_goes_here)  } %>